# How does one mines a glacier tile?

Tags: freeciv

It seems that it is possible only later in game. I'd suppose that this is conditional to the discovery of a certain technology, but I cannot seem to find a reference to that effect.

Does anyone knows ?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform glaciers into tundra. Transforming terrain is only possible with engineers, which replace workers once you have the **Explosives** tech.

This image sums up all the possible terrain alterations (classic ruleset):
[image]

And here's the extensive wiki page: https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Terrain.